# Некорректный вывод данных модели

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

**Модель:**

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**Контроллер:**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{

    [HttpGet]
    public ViewResult ShowProduct()
    {
        return View(new Product());
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public ViewResult ShowProduct(Product product)
    {
        product.ProductId = 100;
        product.Name = "Test";
        return View(product);
    }

}
```

**View:**

```
@model HelperMethods.Models.Product

@using (Html.BeginForm("ShowProduct", "Home"))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ProductId);
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name);

    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
}
```

Пример простой, я создаю пустую форму. Пользователь вводит данные, к примеру, какой-то текст и отправляет форму на сервер. Контроллер получает модель из формы изменяет введенные данные обратно же показывает эту форму. Вот только эти строки

```
product.ProductId = 100;
product.Name = "Test";
```

Не имеют никакого эффекта, в форме остается все равно то что ввел пользователь. Почему так происходит? И как это обойти?

Comment: Как я понимаю, проблема в том, что не выставляются эффекты на форму?

Comment: @Varagian, именно так. В форме, после обработки запроса, я ожидаю увидеть 100 и Test, а там остаются старые введенные пользователем значения.

Comment: Проблема в ModelBinder, если возвращать из того же метода тот же самый объект модели, то изменения не подхватываются, если не очистить ModelState. Это на сколько я знаю.

Comment: Было просто предположение. Думал, что нужно указать `FormMethod.Post` у `BeginForm` и немного более общий тип задать - `ActionResult`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что модель присутствует в словаре ModelState и если не удалить из него поля модели, которые вы хотите изменить, то и эффекта никакого не будет. Допустим:

```
ModelState.Remove(nameof(Product.ProductId));
product.ProductId = 100;
```

После этого изменения в Id будут видны, но лучше возвращать новый объект модели с измененными свойствами, или делать так:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public ViewResult ShowProduct(Product model = null)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult EditProduct(Product product)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid) {
                //или var newProduct = new Product()...
                product.Name = "NewName";
                product.ProductId = 150;

                //HTTP 302 и новый GET запрос от браузера с данным объектом
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(ShowProduct), product);
            }
            return View("ShowProduct", product);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Значит вспомогательный методы типа TextBoxFor сначала будут искать значение модели в ModelState, а только потом, если не нашли в том что я им передам в конструкторе?

Comment: ModelState.Remove(nameof(Product.ProductId)); решило все проблемы

Comment: @koks_rs я бы сказал, что при возвращении модели и View как ответ на запрос фреймворк ставит приоритет над данными из ModelState. Но возможно меня кто-то поправит в этом плане.

Comment: *View из которой пришел POST на сервер